# How to map already uploaded s3 image with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

**My workflow**

I have created a bucket in s3.

When somebody drops an image over there an SNS notification comes to my rails app in response got the image name.

By the image name, I can get the user info.

Now I need to create an active storage relation with the user which will map that s3 URL in active storage table.

Comment: Please check out this documentation for getting s3 image https://chrisherring.co/posts/private-files-for-your-rails-app-using-s3

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is fine. But I want to know how can I link an already uploaded file into s3 to an object via active storage.
Like user  has_one_attached :image (where the image is already uploaded to s3)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can the rails app access the file through s3?

You can attach an existing using an IO object as documented here:

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects

Comment: Do you suggest downloading the file from s3? But the file is already in s3. I don't want to do extra network things.